# Expectation of Matrix's Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I have an issue about find expectation of deteminant

Give a symmetric matrix, It has tree entries which is uniform random variable U(-60;60). Find expectation of Matrix's determinant

Please help me. I don't know how to find it
Thank a lot

Comment: This sounds quite a difficult problem in general. But what is your specific matrix? It may be more tractable.

Comment: I just know that it is symetric matric with three uniform entries, That's all my information.

Comment: hint: use the definition of the determinant (sum over permutations with signs), notice that only those permutations that have only cycles of length 2 contribute (and all of them contribute the same value), find the number of such permutations

Comment: Do you mean it is $\pmatrix{A & B\cr B & C\cr}$ where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent $U(-60,60)$?  Or could it be a bigger matrix that has other entries that are not random variables?

Comment: It could a bigger matrix, no have any limit

Answer (score 0):

Let $$M=\pmatrix{A & B\cr B & C\cr}.$$

where $A,B,C$ are assumed $U(-60,60)$ **and independent**.

By linearity of mathematical expectation, and independence of $A,C$:

$$E(\det(M))=E(AC-B^2)=\underbrace{E(A)E(C)}_{= 0}-E(B^2).$$

Using the fact that $V(B)=E(B^2)-E(B)^2=E(B^2)$ and the formula for the variance of a uniform distribution that can be found in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)),

$$E(\det(M))=-\dfrac{1}{12}(b-a)^2=-\dfrac{1}{12}(60-(-60))^2=-\dfrac{1}{12}(120)^2=-100.$$

Comment: Loosely connected, but very interesting: (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13008/expected-determinant-of-a-random-nxn-matrix)

Comment: why is your matrix $2\times2$?

Comment: @user8268 Because the OP says "t(h)ree entries".

Comment: ah! I didn't know how to interpret trees as matrix entries

Comment: @user8268 Indeed, "tree entries" would be rather special...  one should give to the set of trees at least a ring structure...

Comment: Has three entries following uniform variable. It doesn't mean this matrix only have 2x2 dimension, right?

Comment: @Beginner First of all, is my computations clear in the $2 \times 2$ case ?Furthermore, do you mean that you have coopied the text Do you mean that you have copied your text but are not sure of the interpretation: if it is three (not tree) entries, i think the interpretation I have given is the most likely, that's all.